# Passing two parametres in url in octobercms

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-partial

I must update a existing Octobercms project and it has url like this:
 `<a class="page-link" href="{{ 'catalog/category/' | page({'category': category.slug'}) }}" >Все товары</a>`

And url in category page is this:
`url = "/catalog/:category?"`

How can I pass two parametres in url I tried this:
 `<a class="page-link" href="{{ 'catalog/category/' | page({'category': category.slug, 'second_parameter':'1'}) }}" >Все товары</a>`  and changed url in category page to `url = "/catalog/:category?/:second_parameter?`
but it did not help? Who can help me?

Comment: Does "it did not help" mean, you got an error message? If that's the case, it would be helpful to share it with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is the page's Filename name, as shown in the screenshot

[image]

Use it and create a link as shown below, it will work.

[image]

```
{{ 'test-pg'|page({'param1': 'one', 'param2': 'two'}) }}
```

Output

[image]

```
http://localhost:8000/test-pg/one/two
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: thank you! you solved my problem but I could not upvote for your answers due to lack of reputation

Comment: most welcome :), its ok np, you can just mark answer as correct